# Are there many examples of VC dimension being infinite?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

I could only find one such hypothesis set: sign(sine(wx))

What could be some other examples?

Comment: If you think about exactly what mathematical property makes that example work, you should be able to generate an endless list of possibilities.